# The correct Eclipse/Android device configuration for HTC Sensation XE

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to create an Android Virtual Device in Eclipse which matches HTC Sensation XE. What configuration options should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old configuration I took for my HTC AVD, but you can try !

HTCSensation

```
Google APIs Level 9
SD 8GB
Screen 540x960
hw.dPad=no
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.trackBall=no
vm.heapSize=24
hw.ramSize=1024
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating AVD...

**1-Select api lable 10 (2.3.4)

2-select 'Resolution' and fill 540 * 960**